# Servlet not working properly

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch data from the mysql and display it in the browser using servlet. Below is my servlet code. But when I tried to execute the given code the browser opens up but doesnot display anything. I tried changing database, table but nothing worked for me. Netbeans also doesnot give any error

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
       @Override
       public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                     throws ServletException, IOException
       {


              response.setContentType("text/html");
              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();        


              Connection con;
              try{

                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/servlet","root","");               
                     PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from user");
                     if (con!=null)
                     {

                         out.println("connected");
                  }
                     else{

                         out.println("disconnected");
                     }

                     ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();                
                     /* Printing column names */

                     while(rs.next())
                        {
                            out.println(rs.getString(1));
                            out.println(rs.getString(2));
                        }


              }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e2)
                {

                }

              finally{out.close();
                }
       }

}
```

Comment: Use debugging option in netbeans so that you can find where the problem exist?

Comment: check db url, try to debug your servlet, don't suppress the exceptions (may be that's why there is no error trace in IDE).

Comment: Not able to submit breakpoint FieldBreakpoint chaitra11.View.jScrollPane1, reason: Breakpoint belongs to disabled source root 'C:\Users\DajuVai\Documents\NetBeansProjects\chaitra11\src'. See Window/Debugging/Sources.

But chaitra11 is different project

Comment: print exception  and check your DB connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have following line at the end of the method ie. before out.close();

```
out.flush();
```